# Object `pd.series` not found

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

i have installed pandas in anaconda 3, i try to run my first pandas code on anaconda and it is showing me error, this is an example of the code i run

```
import pandas as pd
  pd.series?

fruits = ['mango', 'orange', 'lemon' ]
  pd.series(fruits)
```

i try to run the pd.series it is giving me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-efbecfd378d2> in <module>
  1 fruits = ['mango', 'orange', 'lemon' ]
 ----> 2 pd.series(fruits)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
261             return _SparseArray
262 
--> 263         raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
264 
265 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'series
```

Comment: `pd.Series` the first letter

Comment: Check the documentation you find out, it's `pd.Series(fruits)`

Comment: [CapWords](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) is the standard for class names, so we get Series and DataFrame

Comment: thanks, problem solved, it is actually pd.series I used instead of pd.Series.

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax would be:

```
import pandas as pd

fruits = ['mango', 'orange', 'lemon' ]
pd.Series(fruits)
```